# htaccess file, how to make it work threw mysql DB?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, seo

thanks for your time :)

I want to create an htaccess file that will redirect my pages after it loads it from the DB.

1) I have a DB that I'm inserting in to it row like:
(page_id, page_url_name) --> example (5,'about-us'), (6,'contact-us')

2) I'll be creating many new pages in the future that I'll add to the DB, and I would like the htaccess file to understand it without changing it.

3)I dont have a problem on how to write the htaccess file'
only the problem how to make him to read from the DB.

an example I saw on an htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) seo.php [L]
```

but I could understand the seo.php file there....

PLEASE help me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it without a PHP file though. There's an interesting discussion on the subject on [this page](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?623335-getting-htaccess-to-read-from-mysql-database). On my own website I use a single PHP file that acts as a director, perhaps that is what you are looking for.

-addition-

I use this in my PHP file to get the path parts:

```
$path = (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? strtolower(substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1)) : '');
$crumbpath = array ();
```

And this in my htaccess to treat files without an extension as a PHP file:

```
<Files ~ "^[^\.]+$">
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

You can see it in action at onderwaterwereld.org. library is the PHP file, anything after it is in my crumbpath array, which I use to read from the database.

Comment: thanks! could you pls add a small explanation on your method?